# im having trouble with my pod file while trying to set up react native iOS app

Tags: react-native, terminal, cocoapods, podfile

im using react native cli and tried to start up my iOS emulator and I keep getting pod file errors and I dont know how I could fix it

Invalid `Podfile` file: unexpected token at ''.

## from /Users/mattanglim/new /localy_moduleios/ios/Podfile:32

## -------------------------------------------

> use_native_modules!

## -------------------------------------------

here is my pod file

version im running is
react-native 0.73.1
ruby 2.6.10
gem cocoapods 1.13

````
# Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded
#
# To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
# ```
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'YourProjectName' do
  # ...
  use_native_modules!
  # ...
end

  target 'localy_moduleiosTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
end
````